# How to sum rows using multiple columns as criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a pseudo inbound-outbound inventory problem where I have material coming into a Warehouse via POs.  Then, that material is transfered to another warehouse via TRSFR. The added complexity is that lbs can be Transfered again to a different warehsoue via another TRSFR.

The main problem I want to solve is tracking lbs that are transfered from the original PO, and follow those lbs to subsequent TRSFRs while using its volumeLBs to limit the number of lbs that can be transfered from a PurchaseID to subsequent TRSFRs. Also, I want the calculation to start over once a new PO comes in for that Warehouse.

This table:

[image]

is an example of what I'd like to see for just one product. There are 2 POs in this time span for Warehouse AB with multiple TRSFRs that take place (text of table is below):

```
productkey| PurchaseID| ActivityType| Into_WHKey| From_WHKey| PurchaseDate| volumeLBs| TRSFRed_Lbs| How TRSFRed_Lbs should be found
       123|        001|           PO|         AB|           |     1/6/2016|    21,000|      16,000| (Found by summing the volumeLBs of future PurchaseIDs whose ActivityType = TRSFR and From_Whkey = the Into_WHKey of this PurchaseID and stopping the calculation when there is another 'PO' ActivityType for the same Into_WHKey... the extro 1,000 comes from a TRSFR that was applied to a later PO but had leftover volume)  
       123|        002|        TRSFR|         CD|         AB|     1/8/2016|     5,000|       4,000| (Found by summing the volumeLBs of future PurchaseIDs whose ActivityType = TRSFR and From_Whkey = the Into_WHKey of this PurchaseID and stopping the calculation when there is another 'PO' ActivityType for the same Into_WHKey)  
       123|        003|        TRSFR|         EF|         CD|    1/14/2016|     4,000|          - | ("0" Since there are no future PurcahseIDs whose ActivityType = TRSFR and From_WhKey = the Into_WHKey of this PurcahseID  
       123|        004|        TRSFR|         CD|         AB|    1/15/2016|    10,000|       7,000|  
       123|        005|           PO|         AB|           |     3/6/2016|    14,000|      14,000| (Limited to 14,000 because that is all that is available from this PurchaseID, the extro 1,000 will be applied to an earlier PO)  
       123|        006|        TRSFR|         CD|         AB|    3/16/2016|    15,000|          - |  (14,000 applied to PO dated 3/6/2016, 1,000 applied to PO dated 1/6/2016)
       123|        007|        TRSFR|         GH|         CD|    5/26/2016|     7,000|          - |
```

I'm pulling all of this data from a temp table called #All_Data.  Here is the code I've written.

```
exec spDropTable '#ApplyTRSFRs'  
select
    a.productkey  
    ,a.PurchaseID  
    ,a.ActivityType  
    ,a.Into_WHKey  
    ,a.PurchaseID  
    ,a.ActivityType  
    ,a.Into_WHKey  
    ,a.From_WhKey  
    ,a.PurchaseDate  
    ,a.volumeLBs  
    ,case when a.activitytype = 'PO' then lead(a.volumeLBs,1,0) Over (Partition By (a.productkey) Order by a.purchaseorderdate)  
        when a.activitytype = 'TRSFR' then lead(a.volumeLBs,1,0) Over (Partition By (a.productkey) Order by a.purchaseorderdate)  
        else '0'  
        end as TRSFRed_Lbs  

into #ApplyTRSFRs  
from #AllData a
```

Major areas I need help with are:
1. Limiting  the # of lbs that can be transfered from a PO (by using its volumeLBs as the max), and
2. Once a new PO is issued,  only use that new PO to transfer lbs from -once that new PO has had all of it's lbs transfered, then it is OK to go back and transfer lbs from an older PO (if there are still lbs available on any older PO).

Comment: What is the link in the question?

Comment: I am *not* clicking that link.  If it's relevant to your question, you should include the content on here, not on some offsite location with a shady address.

Comment: a table in excel.  I'm too new to SO to post images, was trying to get around having to type in all of the data manually

Comment: Usually people just use `copy`/`paste`...

Comment: You put the tag MySQL, but the query using window functions, not supported by MySQL . So what RDBMS you are using ?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: That is not a shady link. It's the upload link that SO provides for images. @samK13, I often use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to make nice ASCII tables of my data that work very nicely here on SO. It's worth a bookmark.

Comment: ty for the bookmark @JNevill!  The link was initially the entire webpage address to the image I saved via gmail.  After @Siyual's post, i edited to SO's upload link (being so new to this I didn't realize SO had this function). Thanks again!